# save original message use TO

Tags: java, groovy, apache-camel

I am new in camel world. I wrote some code, it looks ugly:

```
   from('component:params')
        .process(someValidator())
        .process{
            def producerTemplate = lookup('template', ProducerTemplate.class)
            // I create NEW exchange because I need original in.body data in next routers
            def exchange = new DefaultExchange(context)
            exchange.in.body = someTransformation(it.in.body)
            def result = producerTemplate.send(SOMEWHERE, exchange)
            if (result.exception) throw result.exception
        }
        .process(someActionWithOriginalExchange(it.body.in))
```

I created addition exchange class here. I don't think it good idea. 
But when I try to rewrite it use "transform" and "to" I faced some problem:

```
    from('component:params')
        .process(someValidator())
        .process{// or maybe transform, I guess it doesn't matter here
            it.in.body = someTransformation(it.in.body)
        }
        .to(SOMEWHERE)
        .process(someActionWithOriginalExchange(??? how can I get original exchange????))
```

I don't understand how can I save original message body?

Comment: suggest assessing the code on this page http://camel.apache.org/file.html

Answer (score 1):

you can just call `exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage()` inside of a Bean or Processor